# How to define context parameters in the WebSphere config, instead of the web.xml?

Tags: websphere, web.xml, context-param

With Tomcat, with a `<Parameter>` placed inside a `<Context>` (e.g. in Tomcat's `server.xml`), it is possible to define context parameters for a web app outside of the web app itself, i.e. without having to change the `web.xml`.

This is convenient in cases where the same `war` is being deployed on multiple servers, and you'd like to configure the web app in each case, but this without having to modify the content of the `war`.

For more on this feature in the context of Tomcat, see the [Tomcat doc on context parameters](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters). Does WebSphere provide a similar capability?

Comment: You might find this article useful: http://glezen.org/howto/AppConfig/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional way to define environment-specific information for Java EE web module is to use `<env-entry>` in web.xml, for example:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>entryName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>1</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Then the value of an entry can be obtained through JNDI in `java:comp/env` namespace.

The value can be specified during deployment via WAS-specific deployment descriptor or changed later in WAS console (Enterprise Applications / your_app / Web Module Properties / Environment entries for Web modules)